# When does a power series converge to a rational function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, rational-functions

Are there any results to determine whether the given power series of real variable converges to a rational function? I mean just analyzing the coefficients of the series. One way is to find the sum function which is not always easy to find.

Comment: The coefficients must satisfy a linear recursion, is that the sort of thing you are after?  Of course, if you only have the coefficients numerically, it might not be clear whether or not they satisfy such a recursion.

Comment: I have no idea about this stuff. But I guess you are on the same lines as Robert Israel.

Comment: The [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) contains the (brief) proof.

Comment: This is the analog of saying that the decimal expansions of rational numbers are (eventually) periodic.  As in that case, if you only have a numerically computed list of coefficients you can't really decide much (though you might form useful conjectures).

Comment: Thanks for the link. It is useful. However, I have a power series which is not a Taylor series.

Comment: You mean it is defined about a point other that $0$?  That doesn't change anything.

Comment: I mean I am dealing with an example (which I haven't posted here) which is not a Taylor series. So I cannot really apply the result provided by Robert Israel. There could be the power series which are not Taylor series converging to rational functions.

Comment: Well, no.  Rational functions are equal to their Taylor series in a neighborhood of any point in which they are defined.    Thus, there's no meaningful difference between "Taylor series" and "power series" in this context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A power series is the Taylor series of a rational function if and only if its terms satisfy a constant-coefficient linear recurrence
$$ a_n = \sum_{j=1}^m c_j a_{n-j}$$
for all sufficiently large $n$, where $m$ and $c_j$ are constants.

EDIT: This is certainly well known, and easier to prove than to find a printed reference.  If $R(x) = A(x)/B(x)$ with $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ polynomials, then $B(x) R(x) = A(x)$ gives you the recurrence $\sum_i b_i r_{k-i} = 0$ for $k > \text{degree}(A)$, where $b_i$ are the coefficients of $B(x)$ and $r_i$ the Maclaurin coefficients of $R(x)$.  Conversely, if $\sum_{j=0}^m c_j a_{k-i} = 0$
for $k > n$, that says $B(x) G(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $\le n$ where $G(x)$ is the generating
function $\sum_k a_k x^k$ and $B(x) = \sum_{j=0}^m c_j x^j$.

Comment: This may be true, but is in no way obvious.You should give a reference.

Comment: @Robert Israel, That is an amazing result! Could you please provide me a reference.