# Prove that the series converges for $|z| <1$ to a rational function

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, power-series

Suppose that the power series $\sum a_nz^n$ has a recurring sequence of coefficients;
that is, $a_{n+k} = a_n$ for some fixed positive integer $k$ and all $n$. Prove that the series
converges for$ |z| < 1$ to a rational function $p(z)/q(z)$ where $p, q$ are polynomials, and that the roots of $q$ are all on the unit circle.
What happens if $ a_{n+k} = a_{n}/k$ instead?

I was thinking of using the ratio test but didn't really get anywhere with it.

Comment: Group it into a geometric series with ratio $z^k$.  And I don't think you mean $a_{n/k}$ but $a_n/k$.

Comment: The radius of convergence is $R=1/L$ where $L=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3110476.

Answer (score 1):

As the coefficients repeat periodically, the first series can be written as

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty A(z)z^{ki}= A(z)\sum_{i=0}^\infty z^{ki}=\frac{A(z)}{1-z^k}$$ where $A$ denotes a polynomial of degree $k-1$ (made from the $a_n$). It indeed converges absolutely for $|z|<1$.

For the second series, you can observe that the denominators will be increasing powers of $k$, repeated $k$ times and the series is

$$A(z)\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{z^{ki}}{k^i}=\frac{A(z)}{1-\dfrac{z^k}{k}}.$$

This is again a rational function and it converges for $|z|<\sqrt[k]k$.

Comment: Could explain why the first series can be writen as $\sum_{i=0}^\infty A(z)z^{ki}$, and also why for the second one？ Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Riemann: because the coefficients repeat periodically. Try an example.

Comment: @ Yves Daoust  :Thank you !  you are right!

Comment: @YvesDaoust could you elaborate more on A(z)? I know it is a reccuring sequence of coefficient such that $a_{n+k} = a_n$ but i do not understand furthermore you had.

Comment: why is $z^n$ in the series now $z^{ki}$ ?

Comment: @Riemann if you understood why the series was written it that way, could you please explain it to me?

Comment: @ pop  as Yves Daoust said, you can try an example (for example k=2 or 3), and then you will konw why!