# Proving that an integral defines a rational function without evaluating

Tags: integration, analysis, rational-functions

For $x\in\mathbb{R}$ define
$$I(x):=\int_0^\infty t e^{-t} \sin(xt) dt.$$
It can be shown that $$I(x)=\frac{2 x}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}.$$

**Question:** Can we use a suitable characterization of rational functions to verify that $I(x)$ defines a rational function *directly on the integral expression, without evaluating*?

Comment: Maybe compute the coefficents of the power series for $I(x)$ and check that they obey a linear recurrence? (see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3110486)